# Is it possible to prevent the removal of the comma with empty __VA_ARGS__ in Visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++, macros, preprocessor, variadic-macros

On Visual Studio 2005 I have a macro that looks like this (examplified!!):

```
#define MY_CALL(FUN, ...) \
  if(prepare(x, y)) {     \
    FUN(__VA_ARGS__);     \
  }
/**/
```

As long as the function takes at least one argument, I'm fine.

When the function takes zero arguments, the preprocessor "helpfully" removes the "trailing comma", expanding something like this:

```
if(prepare(x y)) { funct(); }
```

Great, isn't it?

How can I fix this macro, so that it'll work with zero `__VA_ARGS__` on Visual C++ (VS 2005)?

---

Apparently [this is a bug in VS2005](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/278752/comma-missing-when-using-va-args).

Comment: What are `x` and `y` - are they macro arguments? If no, preprocessor shouldnt modify `prepare(x,y)` to `prepare(x y)`. If yes, where are they - you didnt mention

Comment: @Ajay: prepare is a normal function. x y are just example arguments to this function. Nothing to do with the macro.

Comment: I am wondering why preprocesor would remove the unrelated comma between x and y. I have written similar macros for variable arguments in marco, and I havent encountered this issue.

Comment: Yes, and the macros compile for VS2008 and VS2010 also!

Comment: @Ajay: You *do* also have `whatever(__VA_ARGS__)` and not `whatever(something, __VA_ARGS__)`, do you?

Comment: No, I don't have such macro. You may refer this: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/278752/comma-missing-when-using-va-args
Which clearly states VS2005 has this bug even in SP1. I compiled it in VS2008 and it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, I do not use Visual C++ anymore (and as so cannot verify this works), but can you try this?

```
#define MY_CALL(FUN, ...) \
  if(prepare(x, y)) {     \
    int fail[] = {0,}     \
    FUN(__VA_ARGS__);     \
  }
```

Using gcc 4.2, both `{0,}` and `{0}` are allowed in that context, so if the comma gets deleted or not it would not matter. However, I am not certain whether that is generally accepted in the spec, a commonly implemented extension, or something specific to gcc.

If the `{0,}` syntax *is* allowed by Visual C++, then this would hopefully solve your problem (assuming I understand correctly that the most recent comma before `__VA_ARGS__` is what is being incorrectly deleted, regardless of where it is appearing in the syntax).

Comment: Thanks! I inserted the "line" `"dum","my";` instead and this worked.

Comment: Ah ha! That's even better! ;P